# SSRS display basic information

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join, reporting-services

if the employee takes leave the data is shown

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcfd7.png)

**Desired Output**

but if another employee hasn't take leave the basic information should be show in given fields

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWoAG.png)

i want the basic information fields to be filled whether he takes leave or not

this is the query

```
  select LeaveRequest.LeaveRequestID,LeaveRequest.EmployeeID,userName,departmentName,designationName,RequestDate
  ,IsApproved,ApprovedDate,StartDate,EndDate,Name,PartOFDay 
  fromLeaveRequest
  inner join LeaveType
  on LeaveRequest.TypeID=LeaveType.TypeID

  inner join LeaveRequestDetails
  on LeaveRequest.LeaveRequestID=LeaveRequestDetails.LEaveRequestID

  inner join EmployeeInformation
  on LeaveRequest.EmployeeID=EmployeeInformation.employeeID

  inner join Departments
  on Departments.departmentID=EmployeeInformation.departmentID

  inner join Designations
  on Designations.designationID=EmployeeInformation.designationID

  where EmployeeInformation.employeeID=@empID**
```

Comment: As good practice, I always start with the table that contains the data that will always be present, in this case your EmployeeInformation table. then do LEFT joins to tables that may or may not have related data. It's much simpler to visualise I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the INNER JOIN on EmployeeInformation as it's filtering out any employeeIDs which are not in the LeaveRequest table.
Try changing it to a right join instead:

```
right join EmployeeInformation
  on LeaveRequest.EmployeeID=EmployeeInformation.employeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your Inner join with left outer join.

thanks,
SK